# Unable to share data in purview

Tags: azure, azure-purview

Explanation:
I followed the steps in the link below to share data in purview but still keep getting errors

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/purview/how-to-receive-share?tabs=azure-portal

Error Message:

Failed to attach share "demopurviewshare01"

An asset must either be mapped to a newly created container or to a container which was previously used to receive in-place share data. Correlation Id: 5dcd643d-5502-45a9-9923-944c04df404d

I have tried the steps in the link below:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/purview/how-to-receive-share?tabs=azure-portal

1.Gave storage blob owner privileges to both source and tagrget data lakes
2.created  2 storage accounts  in the same region and subscription
3.I already registered the allowdatashare and allow datashreinheroregion
4.registered both storage accounts in the same pruview data map and collection but I still get the error message below:
Failed to attach share "demopurviewshare01"

An asset must either be mapped to a newly created container or to a container which was previously used to receive in-place share data. Correlation Id: 5dcd643d-5502-45a9-9923-944c04df404d

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to do two data shares by following the steps highlighted on this documentation: [Share Azure storage data with Microsoft Purview data sharing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/purview/how-to-share-data?tabs=azure-portal). Kindly ensure that all the steps have been followed for a successful data share.

Also,based on your description and the error message, it seems like you might be trying to map the shared data to a container that already has data or was not properly configured to receive shared data. I would suggest that you ensure that you are mapping the shared data to a new and empty container in the target data lake. If the container already has data, it might be causing conflicts.

Also,ensure that the user performing the operation has the necessary permissions on both the source and target data lakes.